# How can I move a directory to a newly created partition with ansible?

Tags: ansible, centos7

I have an aws image I'm using which didn't allocate enough space for the root partition (4 gigs, really!?)  so I'm trying to make a new partition for /opt and move the existing /opt directory over to the new partition using ansible.

I've already created the partition and created a filesystem on that partition using ansible.  However, I'm not sure of a clean way to do the copy of the old /opt on the root partition to the new partition.

I can't mount the new partition as /opt since /opt already exists.  If I was doing things by hand I'd probably mount the new partition to some random name, copy everything over, then remount the partition as opt, but I'm not sure of a clean way to do that in ansible, ideally while being idempotent, or at least only doing the copy if opt is still on the root partition.

If it matters this is running on a centos 7 vm.

Comment: `rsync -Pau` is my favorite, and as for the "only if opt is on the root" the `ansible_disks` facts should help with that, or investigating `/etc/fstab`; this question is super broad, so you'll want to just pick a strategy and the ask questions about the errors that it produces

Comment: `I can't mount the new partition as /opt since /opt already exists` <= this will not help solving your issue but is actually totally possible. You can even mount on an already mounted mount-point- Only the latest mounted filesystem will be visible and accessible though. (Leant the hard way when one day someone had overridden an nfs mount mounting it twice with 2 different sources....).